# netdata alarm on server login

Tags: configuration, netdata

so I'm pretty new to netdata. I have an instance running on my server and I wanted to setup a few alarms to my telegram.
The examples given by netdata worked pretty well (cpu load, disk usage, ...). I also wanted to add an alarm when someone logs in to the server even though I'm using SSH keys for login. Why? Just because I want to learn how to do it.
Anyway. I don't really understand their documentation since I'm mostly a developer and no Linux-sysadmin.

So far I added config files to `/etc/netdata/health.d/`. But I don't understand how the `system_login.conf` file should look like.
I tried using this blog post but I don't quite understand how to apply it: [How to monitor and troubleshoot systemd-logind](https://blog.netdata.cloud/logind-monitoring)
What do I have to put into the `alarm` property? For the `on` property I'd guess it is `systemd-logind`. On further research I found another blog post ([systemd-logind monitoring with Netdata](https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/agent/collectors/python.d.plugin/logind)
) which says to edit some `python.d.conf` file that I don't have. I'm pretty confused right now and have no clue how to write the config file.